# The etymology of the word 'turnip'

Tags: etymology

I'm looking for an etymology for the word **turnip**. Now, According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turnip#Etymology):

> From turnepe, probably from **turn** + Middle English nepe, from Old English nǣp, from Latin nāpus.[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turnip#Etymology) **The component turn** may be due to the round shape of the plant as though turned on a lathe, **or because it must be turned and twisted to be harvested**.

I tried to realize and check if there is a real association between this etymology to the reality:

- As far as I know, radish as the same characteristics of harvesting.
- It is difficult to see that turnip has a special way of turning while harvesting ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3Bnf_K8AW4) video shows an harvest of turnip)

According to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/turnip):

> c. 1500, turnepe, probably from turn (**from its shape, as though turned
>   on a lathe**) + Middle English nepe "turnip," from Old English næp, from
>   Latin napus "turnip." The modern form of the word emerged late 18c.

But also this etymology isn't simple, since we can find a lot of fruits and vegetables with a 'turn on a lathe' form.

So it's difficult to understand these etymologies. It may be that it has an association with turning but not in the way it's described there. Is there another possible reasonable etymology for this word?

Comment: Actually, someone took a bite of one, almost puked, and muttered "TERN-UP" as they ran for the toilet.

Comment: The word for something doesn't necessarily have to describe something unique about it. It's often just some quality that the original namer noticed. If you call someone "shorty", they're not the only short person you know.

Answer (score 1):

[The Concise Dictionary of English Etymology](https://books.google.it/books?id=aDhGlKL3h00C&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=turnip%20etymology&source=bl&ots=t6DOd549No&sig=ACfU3U1BJO8cuuqZE9pheGs0XsA4bLW1ZA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXzozv5pbmAhUDyaQKHToXCmQ4ChDoATABegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=turnip%20&f=false) agrees with you sources on the latter part of the term but on the former they suggest:

> The former  part appears to be from French *tuor* in the sense of “wheel” to signify its round shape; it looks as if it had been turned. *A turner’s wheel* was formerly  called *a turn* in English and *tour* in French.